# input type= email, URL, and search have a 1px left and right padding in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

If you use Google Chrome (At least that is the only browser I know that does this), then go to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7KZMe/) uncheck the "Normalized CSS" checkbox and look at the input elements.

In Google Chrome the email, URL, and search input fields have a 1px padding all around, but the text and password fields have only a top and bottom padding.

Why, it only makes it harder to format?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
input[type=search]{
padding: 0;}
```